# Trying to convert existing query to a stored procedure, gis

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert the existing query that returns all records within a particular distance from a point (geometry)

I have created a stored procedure within mysql-workbench which takes lat long and the distance, I am expecting to get the same results as the query (which returns all records within the specified distance. Where am I going wrong, I am trying to pass the values for lat and long to another spatial function to create the user location. but it seems t be failing here

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `findNearby`(

IN lat VARCHAR(255),
IN longVal VARCHAR(255),
IN distanceFrom INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE user_location geometry default ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)', 4326 ) ;
SET user_location = ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(lat longVal)', 4326 );
SELECT 
    *,
    ST_AsText(`location`) AS `pos_wkt`,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, user_location) AS `distance`
FROM
    `business_details`
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, user_location) <= distanceFrom;
END

SET @user_location = ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(30 50)', 4326 );
  SELECT 
    *,
    ST_AsText(`location`) AS `pos_wkt`,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, @user_location) AS `distance`
FROM
    `business_details`
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, @user_location) <= (1000*5000);
```

> ## 3037 - Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work this one out.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `findNearby`(

IN lat VARCHAR(255),
IN longVal VARCHAR(255),
IN distanceFrom INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE user_location geometry default ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)', 4326 ) ;
DECLARE pointString varchar(255);
set pointString = concat('POINT(', lat, ' ', longVal, ')');
SET user_Location = ST_GeomFromText(  pointString, 4326 );
SELECT 
    *,
    ST_AsText(`location`) AS `pos_wkt`,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, user_location) AS `distance`
FROM
    `business_details`
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(`location`, user_location) <= distanceFrom * 1000;
END
```